# Scope of variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, scoping

I would like to know the scope of the variable `$crazy` in the following PowerShell script:

```
function Test1 { 
    Write-Host $crazy 
}  

function Main { 
    $crazy = Read-Host "Type anything" 
    Test1 
} 

Main
```

I was expecting `$crazy` to be only visible within `Main` function but, to my surprise, the function `Test1` was able to access it. I can guarantee that there's no previously declared `$crazy` variable in my PS session.

I'll be honest I didn't fully understand about_scope so I used ISE to debug through the script and tested the scope of the variable with the following pattern `$<scope>:$crazy` and the variable didn't even appear every scope I've used.

Comment: `$crazy` is local to `function Main{...}`, and can only be seen/read from `Test1` because you call it from inside `Main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `$crazy` is scoped to the Main function, so it is available inside of `Main` and as such available to any function that is called by `Main`. If you were to attempt to call `$crazy` from outside of `Main` you'd find that it was not yet set.  Does that help?